# Как отсортировать столбец за сегодняшним месяцем

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть таблица `order_details` и у меня есть столбец `date`, мне нужно, чтобы был вывод был только тех рядов, где выполняеться условие (вывод за сегодняшим месяцем)

Пытался сделать через 2 инпута, чтобы пользователь вводил от и до, но почемуто не работает?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и сама таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подсказать как правильно будет сделать либо за сегодняшим месяцев, либо как я сделал но без ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT * FROM order_details
    WHERE MONTH(date)=06; --это если нужен июнь.MONTH(date) возвращает месяц из даты.
```